# Flexbox Layout - Move Item out of document flow and centre in screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn flexbox. In my example I would like to move the grey box (contact box) from its natural position in the document to be in the centre of the page.

The first two items (blue column and green column) are 50% width each and stretch to fill the screen.

See picture: 
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id='container-row'>

  <section class='container-column pic-bkg'>

    <nav id='main-nav'>
      <ul id='main-nav-list'>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <section class='container-column solid-bkg'>

  </section>

  <section class='container-column contact-box'>
    contact box
  </section>

</div>
<!-- close id container-row -->
<!-- id container-row is for flexbox 2 column layout -->
```

This is my first time using Flexbox, I cannot figure out how to move just one flex item.

CSS:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}

#container-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;    
    width: 100%;
}

.container-column {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 4em;
}


#main-nav-list {
    display: inline-flex;;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
}

#main-nav-list li {
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.solid-bkg {
    background-color: #0C3134;
}

.pic-bkg {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container-column:nth-child(3){
    background-color: grey;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

[Codepen here:](https://codepen.io/acekicker77/pen/geWYKo?editors=0100)

Comment: Use `position: fixed;` with the [douchebag centering](https://gist.github.com/colintoh/62c78414443e758c9991) and you should be on your way.

Comment: I don't think that can be done with flex as you are sat on top of the other 2 columns, you need to use absolute positioning - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXbwxB?editors=1100

Comment: Yeah...flexbox can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use '.container-column:nth-child(3)' classes content like below and you will get the result.

```
.container-column:nth-child(3) {
   background-color: grey;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   text-align: center;
}
```